# LCD stays blank when it is on and all wiring seems correct

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd

[image: here's an image of the wiring]

So I have to do this project for school and it involves using a lcd display on tinkercad. I followed the wiring on this tutorial here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HelloWorld. When I turn it on, the display is just blank even though I've tried to print.

Here is the code I have for this

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

//TESTING
//ULTRASONIC WORKS
//SERVO WORKS
//BUZZER WORKS
//POTENTIOMETER WORKS

//Variables:

Servo pump;

LiquidCrystal lcd (12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

bool blnPump = true;

long lngTimer = 0;
long lngDistance = 0;

int intPumpTime = 0;
int intLightLevel = 0;
int intCount = 0;

//soundDistance:to use the ultrasonic distance sensor and find the distance of an object above

//input
    //intSignalPin: to indicate which pin to use for the sensor
//output
    //lngDistance: the distance between the sensor and the object in cm

long soundDistance (int intSignalPin)
{
  long lngTime = 0;
  long lngDistance = 0;
  //gather the time is takes for the sound to travel back

  pinMode (intSignalPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite (intSignalPin, LOW);
  delay (2);
  digitalWrite (intSignalPin, HIGH);
  delay (10);
  digitalWrite (intSignalPin, LOW);
  pinMode (intSignalPin, INPUT);
  lngTime = pulseIn (intSignalPin, HIGH);

  //Serial.println (lngTime);
  //calculating the distance

  lngDistance = lngTime * 0.01723;

  return lngDistance;
}

void setup()
{
  pinMode (A0,INPUT);
  pinMode (A1, INPUT);
  pinMode (9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(13, INPUT);
  Serial.begin (9600);

  pump.attach (10);

  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.print ("hello");
}

void loop()
{
  //turning lcd off
  digitalWrite (8, LOW);

  lcd.print ("hello");
  //determining how many times the servo will pump
  intPumpTime = analogRead (A0);

  if (intPumpTime >= 0 && intPumpTime <= 341)
  {
    intPumpTime = 1;
  }

  else if (intPumpTime >= 342 && intPumpTime <= 683)
  {
    intPumpTime = 2;
  }

  else //if (intPumpTime >= 684 && intPumpTime <= 1023)
  {
    intPumpTime = 3;
  }

  //Pumping if theres a hand in range of 5cm to 25cm and pumping different amounts of sanitizer based on potentiometer, playing a tone if it does and turning the lcd on or off based on light level

  if (soundDistance (13) >= 5 && soundDistance (13) <= 25 && blnPump == true)
  {
    //turning lcd on or off
    intLightLevel = analogRead (A1);
    if (intLightLevel <= 300)
    {
      lcd.noDisplay();
    }

    else
    {
      lcd.display();
    }

    //playing tone to indicate its pumping
    tone (8, 500);
    delay (100);
    noTone (8);

    //lighting up led to indicate its pumping
    digitalWrite (9, HIGH);

    //pumping
    for (intCount = 0; intCount < intPumpTime; intCount++)
    {
        pump.write (90);
        delay (1000);
        pump.write (0);
        delay (1000);
    }

    //shutting off the led and turning the servo off
    digitalWrite (9, LOW);
    blnPump = false;

    lngTimer = millis();

    //waiting here to display hand scrubing time, no more sanitizer will be dispensed in this 20 seconds
    while (millis() - lngTimer < 20000)
    {

      if (millis() - lngTimer <= 1000)// && intLightLevel > 300)
      {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print ("19 seconds left");
      }

      else if (millis() - lngTimer > 4000 && millis() - lngTimer <= 5000)// && intLightLevel > 300)
      {
        //blnPump = true;
      }
    }


    //decide if to use LCD or not here
  }

  else
  {
    pump.write (0);
  }

  //Serial.println (soundDistance (13));
  //long lngTest = soundDistance (13);
}
```

Sorry for all the extra code, they're for the other parts. I think I have followed what needs to be followed with inputting the pin into the LiquidCrystal class, the begin method but it just doesn't print.

Comment: For clarification, I inputted the pins into the liquid crystal class near the top under variables. Begin() and print() is in setup

Comment: You're probably taking too much power out of the 5V pin and nothing is getting proper power.  The 5V pin isn't there to power your whole project.  Try using a separate power supply for all the stuff involved there and see if that doesn't help.

Comment: You certainly shouldn't be trying to power a motor or servo off the 5V pin.  That's a good way to end up needing a new Arduino.

Comment: Never thought about that since I've always just used the 5v pin and everything before worked. I'm going to try that out tomorrow

Comment: I hope unused GND pin on LCD is just a mistake in schematic.

Comment: Oh I was messing with the wiring on it, might've accidentally took it off but I don't think it worked with it connected anyways

Comment: Twiddle with contrast potentiometer. Uninitialized LCD usually has first row blacked - wrong contrast results into either nothing is visible or all pixels are black or something inbetween. But there is also possibility it's already burned by missing GND connection. Those LCDs are pretty sensitive to miswiring power lines.

Comment: Most (all?) pins can deliver (source) 20 mA recommendable ( 40 mA max, but better to stay under 20 mA), and there are also maximums for groups of pins. the 5V pin can handle more (not sure out of my head) but it's in the order of 100's of mA, probably too much for the servo, LCD and especially both together.